# Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm. Raw passwords are not stored. Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

I have a signup code

views.py:

```
def signup(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    form = SignupForm()
    return render(req,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password','first_name','last_name']
```

now whenever I try to login with this code the submission is successful but when I go to the admin panel and click on the user, on the password section it says

Password:

Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.

Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user’s password, but you can change the password using http://localhost/admin/auth/user/3/password/.

Comment: This is not how you should *register* a user: the (builtin) signup form hashes the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the built in user creation form so something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you should register a user: the (builtin) signup form hashes the password.

You can do this with:

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
            if hasattr(self, 'save_m2m'):
                self.save_m2m()
        return user
```

Probably you have a custom login-view yourself. There you should check the *hashed* password, not a raw password.

Comment: I still have the issue

Comment: should i add every field invidiously?

Comment: @divyanshundley: this will of course only work for *new* users you register, since the old ones have invalid `password`s...

Comment: I did try but It didn't work

Comment: Exactly how does the user table look like for *newly* created users (so after you changed the `SignupForm`)?